# Silence CMP0048 Warnings in Vendored Projects

Tags: cmake

I have git submodules with `CMakeLists.txt` files that are causing warnings due to CMP0048. The warnings look like this:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at submodule_directory/CMakeLists.txt:24 (project):
  Policy CMP0048 is not set: project() command manages VERSION variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0048" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The following variable(s) would be set to empty:

    PROJECT_VERSION
    PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR
    PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR
    PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I don't control these `CMakeLists.txt` files and I don't want to fork so there's nothing to be done about this and I just want CMake to shut up about it. Using `cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 OLD)` before adding the submodule directories doesn't solve this. (I guess `project()` resets cmake policies?).

Is there anything I can I do about this?

Comment: As the last line suggests, you may use `-Wno-dev` option for `cmake` to suppress all developers warnings. As for using `cmake_policy` in *CMakeLists.txt*, did you try to use it *before first* `project()` call? Also, `NEW` value for the policy has a sence: it gives submodule to control its version by itself, but `PROJECT_VERSION` variable will be restored upon returning from submodule's directory, so your (root) project wouldn't suffer.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't want to suppress *all* developer warnings. Using `cmake_policy()` before the first `project()` doesn't help although placing it above the third and below the second does. (third/second in terms of depth; my project only contains the first `project()` call)

Comment: CMake command `project()` doesn't reset policies, but [cmake_minimum_required](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/cmake_minimum_required.html) does. Probably, this is a reason why `cmake_policy()` works only at specific place. For 3d party modules which you cannot modify or support, using `ExternalProject_Add` has a sence: such a way you may suppress all developers warnings for external project, but do not ignore warnings for your own one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev This looks promising. Setting `SOURCE_DIR` in a `ExternalProject_Add()` seems almost right. The project builds and doesn't issue warnings but I haven't figured out how to access the project's targets and I need to sleep for now.

Comment: Any updates, how to silence this warning for thirdparty projects?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution if you don't care about enabling the policy is just to set [`CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0048`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMPNNNN.html) to `NEW`  at the CMake command line. The following answer shows an alternative that lets you take a more piecemeal approach.

---

There is a more flexible solution in CMake 3.15+ using the [`CMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE_BEFORE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html#code-injection) variable. See my example here:

```
$ tree
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── cmake
│   └── EnableCMP0048.cmake
└── subproj
    └── CMakeLists.txt
```

I assume `subproj/CMakeLists.txt` contains this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12) # Never do this
project(subproj)
```

In `cmake/EnableCMP0048.cmake`, put:

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)
```

In `./CMakeLists.txt`, put:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(test VERSION 1.0.0)

set(CMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE_BEFORE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/EnableCMP0048.cmake")
add_subdirectory(subproj)
unset(CMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE_BEFORE)  # if you don't want to affect subsequent add_subdirectory calls.
```

Now this will enable `CMP0048` and will clear the mentioned variables in the subproject. Given that in your question, you tried to fix this by modifying the policy, I assume that's okay. But if not, you could add another script, `cmake/RestoreProjectVars.cmake`:

```
# Recall the top-level CMakeLists.txt had project(test).
set(PROJECT_VERSION "${test_VERSION}")
set(PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR "${test_VERSION_MAJOR}")
set(PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR "${test_VERSION_MINOR}")
set(PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH "${test_VERSION_PATCH}")
```

and then `set(CMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/RestoreProjectVars.cmake")` before calling `add_subdirectory` to restore those variables after the call.